# React-Native Open error : Cant find module 'jest-hast-map'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cmd, command

I need your help.

I have react-Native project already. When I open, have the problem

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jest-haste-map'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\trackvees-mobile\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:18:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Projects\trackvees-mobile\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Did you fix it?